# fix cloud DNS google and Godaddy automatically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns, godaddy-api

I am using terraform to set-up my infrastructure, but use godaddy for my domain hosting. Unfortunately, every time I set-up my Cloud DNS in GCP the nameservers are random between

```
ns-cloud-{x}1.googledomains.com.  x = a, b, c, d, e
```

which means there is always a manual step to update these in Godaddy.com. Is there any way this can be automated by fixing the ns-cloud nameservers or automate the nameservers at Godaddy?

Comment: There is a Terraform Godaddy plugin. https://github.com/n3integration/terraform-godaddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, I am bit late to the party but you can do this using `n3integration` like @John Hanely said. Below is my code using which I am able to update my godaddy DNS nameservers.

```
# Adding Provider

terraform {
  required_providers {
    godaddy = {
        source = "n3integration/godaddy"
        version = "~> 1.9.1"
    }
  }
}

# Add your godaddy API KEY and Secret

provider "godaddy" {
  key = jsondecode(file("./godaddy.json")).key
  secret = jsondecode(file("./godaddy.json")).secret
} 

# Finally 

resource "godaddy_domain_record" "tfs_domain_record" {
  domain = "yourdomain.com"
  addresses = [google_compute_global_address.tf_external_ip.address]
  nameservers = data.google_dns_record_set.tf_record_set.rrdatas
}
```

> *addresses : Your VM's or Loadbalancer's public IP (static)*
>
> *nameservers : Your cloud DNS nameservers*

Answer (score 1):

GCP randomly selects a letter there as long it's not being used [somewhere else](https://cloud.google.com/dns/quotas#nameserver_limits) (other letter), currently there is no way to select the letter on here directly, but you could create 5 GCP DNS zones that gives you all letters and then you can delete the ones you don't want.

Additionally, perhaps trying the link @John Hanley provided could help you with this as well.